Unable to format RAW microSD card
I have a microSD card that at first won't appear in Finder. I assumed it was broken, but after switching to Windows, the card appeared on File Explorer. When I tried to click on it, though, Windows prompted me to format the disk. After clicking continue, it said “Windows was unable to format this disk.” I went online for some solutions.
One article said to use chkdsk. It said “Unable to format RAW disk” or something close to it as I don't want to switch back and forth repeatedly.
I also tried diskpart but it said something about needing to select a volume first. Lastly, I tried disk management but the “Format” button is grayed out. I couldn't find anything else that I hadn't tried. Is there some kind of software I can use to format it to FAT32? I'm running Windows on a MacBook so I can use software for both.

The answers to this question didn't help.

Sounds like a hardware issue to me, most likely. You can try wiping the card with software, but there's no guarantees and this will wipe all data on the card if it succeeds.

I tried to wipe it but it didn't work.

If Windows doesn't "like" the card (anymore)

What does this mean?

Once SD card can't be formatted by Windows, you should backup data first.

The files aren't important and it doesn't solve the issue.
Before you click that flag button below, please comment so I will know what to change down there⬇

Likely, it's dead. Try opening the card in diskmgmt.msc or DiskGenius toremaove all partitions and then format it. If hat fails, it's a bad card.

This question is similar to: Unable to format RAW SD card?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Superfloppy / No MBR / No partition table
While it is certainly possible that the microSD card went bad, I would like to offer another hypothesis.
Theory: Boot sector hierarchy
The first sector of a disk of any type is typically the MBR. It contains some boot code and a basic partition table. Even the more modern GPT partition table will retain a dummy MBR.
The individual partitions have a VBR as their first sector. It contains some more boot code and key data about the partition, such as the file system used.
Superfloppy
Every once in a while I have come across flash drives and memory cards, especially preformatted factory-new media, which skips the MBR and puts the VBR of the only partition as the first sector.
This is sometimes called superfloppy formatting, as it was commonly used with floppy disks, where having multiple partitions often made little sense.
Windows
In my experience, Windows can react a little odd to superfloppy flash drives. Windows may be able to read and write files from the partition.
But when you try to inquire Windows about the drive, then it will keep telling you that it is MBR-formatted.
Furthermore, cleaning and reformatting the drive to MBR with Diskpart (diskpart.exe) or Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc) will often fail. Here I have had inconsistent experiences across different versions of Windows.
I have no experience with superfloppy media and macOS to share.
Solution: Rufus
Whenever I have come across a superfloppy flash drive, I have simply reformatted it as an MBR drive on Windows using the third-party formatting tool Rufus.
Relatedly, Rufus is able to create superfloppy media - Windows' own formatting tools cannot do that.

The card is dead. This is nothing but an huge and useless tangent.

"Formatting", in the modern sense, involves nothing more than writing certain data to the disk or card. (That is to say, there aren't any special hardware operations that different software would be able to do better than Windows does – while there are other tools for this, ultimately they all do the same thing, i.e. write regular data.)
So if Windows fails to format an SD card (or a USB stick), that pretty much means the card is no longer able to hold data – i.e. it's returning errors to the 'write' requests – and realistically the only solution is to buy a new one.
The same explanation applies for attempts to wipe the card.
(Some USB sticks have manufacturer-specific "MPTool" programs to do a low-level format, which physically resets the flash in some manner, or at least repartitions it to cut out unusable parts, but those aren't easily found, and I don't think I've seen any for SD cards either.
Full SATA/NVMe SSDs can sometimes be "repaired" by using the dedicated 'erase' command – such as ATA "Secure Erase Enhanced", which has managed to temporarily revive two SSDs for me so far – but they still don't tend to last long after that.)

When flash media 'dies', which most likely means that the controller runs out of spare blocks to reallocate bad blocks, it switches to a r/o mode. It enables the user to get data off the medium, but no further write, including formatting, is possible.
